# change application taskbar icon in kde

Tags: taskbar, kde, kde-4

through kmenuedit i can set new menu items and icons... however, once the application starts, it uses its own icon (which has been set elsewhere, i guess). how do i set a different icon for that application?

Answer (score 1):

Any KDE application has the capability of loading and using a different icon than the built-in one on application start. Use the `--icon` option. See the `--help-all` option for further customisations.

Comment: been there, but to no success. what should i type after --icon? i pointed to an svg file but nothing happened. maybe png?

Answer (score 0):

It think there is no general solution for this since the application sets this icon itself, AFAIK. However it might be possible to replace this icon for a specific application. For this I would have to know what application's icon you want to change.

Comment: i was actually thinking of firefox (not a kde app, so --icon won't work here).

Comment: On openSuSE 11.2 (64bit) the icons seem to be in /usr/lib64/firefox/chrome/icons/default/. It might be slightly different for 32bit (probably just lib instead of lib64) or other distributions. Just try whether switching the icons there with other icons of the same format works (keep backups of the icons).